# WCF and HttpSessionState, HttpApplicationState

Tags: wcf

I am migrating a web service to WCF so I can use binary encoding.  I am now realizing that the session calls and application state calls are not recognized.  WCF is supposed to be better then a web service so I am assuming that there is a better way to do things.

1) How do I maintain session and call a web service that uses session?

2) How do I replace the application object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those of you who are migrating a large project and cannot afford to be so ideological, I found a real answer here:

http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/migrating-aspnet-web-services-to-wcf/

Answer (score 3):

In WCF, the best practice is not to have any state whenever possible, since your clients should be calling you with a "per-call" approach - each call from a client gets a new instance of your WCF service class, which is totally independent of anything else, ideally.

If you need to have persistent state, store it in a persistent store - typically a database.

WCF is also by default totally independent of ASP.NET and IIS, and thus cannot leverage the HttpContext, HttpSessionState and so forth objects - since it might be self-hosted in a console app which has no knowledge of IIS, HTTP context etc.

The question is: what exactly do you really use from those HttpSessionState and HttpApplicationState objects? Somehow, you need to abstract that away or solve it some other way, e.g. have the client send you that information (as a parameter on your web service method call, or as a header in the message), or have the client send you a "token" of sorts which allows you to retrieve the relevant info from e.g. a database table.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 4 in Juval Lowy's excellent Programming WCF Services ([link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494/)) is all about Instance Management.  There are sections on Per-Session services and Durable services, each of which might be what you're looking for.

However, Marc's point is very valid.  There are a lot of cons to using session with WCF services, but it is possible.  Lowy discusses a lot of this in some detail.